# How to compose sequence of pipes for gulp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, pipe

I have a common pattern in my `gulpfile.js`:

```
var rev         = require('gulp-rev');
var buffer      = require('gulp-buffer');

gulp.src.some_stuff
  .pipe(anotherStuff)
  .pipe(buffer()) // this line & 4 lines down
  .pipe(rev())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(options.dest))
  .pipe(rev.manifest({ path: 'manifest.json', merge: true }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(options.dest)) // to this
  .pipe(extrastuff)
```

I want to compose these 5 lines to reuse them in my project over a couple of gulp tasks. How can I do that?

I found [multipipe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multipipe) package but it doesn't support passing variables to new pipes (you can see I need to pass `options.dest` in my new pipe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`lazypipe`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lazypipe):

```
var lazypipe = require('lazypipe');

function something(dest) {
  return (lazypipe()
   .pipe(buffer)
   .pipe(rev)
   .pipe(gulp.dest, dest)
   .pipe(rev.manifest, { path: 'manifest.json', merge: true })
   .pipe(gulp.dest, dest))();
}

gulp.src.some_stuff
  .pipe(anotherStuff)
  .pipe(something(options.dest))
  .pipe(extrastuff)
```

Comment: Somehow I can't get it working with the param...
Docs and discussion aren't matching.. (wether to use `.pipe(foo)` or `.pipe(foo())` https://github.com/OverZealous/lazypipe/issues/19

Comment: @Sandrooco It's `.pipe(foo)` when you want to add `foo` to a `lazypipe`. It's `.pipe(foo())` when `foo` is the `lazypipe` itself.

Comment: Then how can I pass a param to the lazypipe?

Comment: Look at the answer. `dest` is a param that is used to construct the `lazypipe`.