# Gulp/Lazypipe: Error: Invalid call to lazypipe().pipe(): argument is not a function

Tags: javascript, build, gulp

I receive the error as stated:

> Error: Invalid call to lazypipe().pipe(): argument is not a function.
>
> Remember not to call stream creation functions directly! e.g.:
>   pipe(foo), not pipe(foo()).

That makes totally sense to me (especially because there are already some related questions), but how can I pass params to the lazypipe?

```
function buildPipes(fileName) {
    return lazypipe()
        .pipe($.concat(fileName))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destFull))
        .pipe($.rename(minFileName))
        .pipe($.babel({
            presets: ["es2015"]
         }))
        .pipe($.uglify({
            compress: {
                hoist_funs: false
            }
         }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
}
```

Another part of my script, consuming the pipe:

```
var vendor = gulp.src(sources.vendor).pipe(buildPipes(fileName));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`lazypipe` docs](https://github.com/OverZealous/lazypipe#usage) give several examples how to pass parameters to plugins. Here's one:

```
var jsTasks = jsHintTasks
    .pipe(gulp.dest, 'build/js');
```

More generalized: for any plugin function `foo` which returns a [`stream.Transform`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_duplex_and_transform_streams) the following conversions apply:

**normal usage -> lazypipe usage**

- `.pipe(foo())` **->** `.pipe(foo)`
- `.pipe(foo(param1))` **->** `.pipe(foo, param1)`
- `.pipe(foo(param1, param2))` **->** `.pipe(foo, param1, param2)`
- etc..

In your case:

```
function buildPipes(fileName) {
  return lazypipe()
    .pipe($.concat, fileName)
    .pipe(gulp.dest, destFull)
    .pipe($.rename, minFileName)
    .pipe($.babel, {
        presets: ["es2015"]
     })
    .pipe($.uglify, {
        compress: {
            hoist_funs: false
        }
     })
    .pipe(gulp.dest, dest);
}
```

Also note that `lazypipe().pipe(foo)` doesn't return a stream. It returns a function that returns a stream, so you need to invoke that function if you want to pipe the constructed lazypipe to another stream. That means instead of:

```
var vendor = gulp.src(sources.vendor).pipe(buildPipes(fileName));
```

You need to do this:

```
var vendor = gulp.src(sources.vendor).pipe(buildPipes(fileName)());
```

(Alternatively you could do the function invocation in the `buildPipe()` function itself as seen in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36373175/5892036))

Comment: Nah, `lazypipe` was written by [OverZealous](http://stackoverflow.com/users/145185/overzealous). I just answer lots of gulp questions because I know it pretty well and there doesn't seem to be a lot of people willing or able to do the same.